# stop reclicking on select option menue with jQuery onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on select then it is fetching data and apply to options. After that when I click on options then the data is fetching again. Problem is reclicking when I choose an option which should not to happen. How to solve this??

```
<select class="form-control m-b" name="agency" id="agency">
   <option selected value="{{$assignment->agency->id}}">{{$assignment->agency->name}}</option>
   <option value="1">None</option>
</select>
```

---

```
$('#agency').on('click', function(){
   getagency();
});


function getagency(){
        var user_id = $('#user').val();
        var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();
        $.ajax({
            'type':'post',
            'url':'{{URL::to('postagency')}}',
            'headers': {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
            'data':{'user_id':user_id},
            'dataType':'json',
            'beforeSend':function(){ $('.row').mask('Please Wait...'); },
            'success':function(resp){
                $('#agency').children('option').empty().remove();
                $.each(resp,function(intex,info){
                  $('<option value="'+ info.id +'">'+ info.name +'</option>').appendTo('#agency');
                  $('.row').unmask();
                });
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: If you want to load the options why don't you load the data when page loads instead of click.

Comment: have a look at jQuery `one` instead of `on`

Comment: As per project requirement to make more dynamics it is needed @HappyCoding

Comment: Thanks @LelioFaieta It's working perfectly.

Comment: You are welcome! @DipankarNaskar will turn it into an answer then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind the action to be executed only once you can do so:
Turn this:

```
$('#agency').on('click', function(){
   getagency();
});
```

into this:

```
$('#agency').one('click', function(){
   getagency();
});
```

and the click function will be binded only the first time you execute it

Answer (score 1):

change your initializing code to ::

```
$('#agency').on('change', function(){
   getagency();
});
```

Comment: @dipankar naskar , Please upvote the answer and accept the answer if it helped you and for others.

Comment: `$('#agency').one('click', function(){
            getagency();
    });`

Comment: @DipankarNaskar OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#agency').one('click', function(){
     getagency();
});
```